# (gedit:1430): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: server, gedit, text-editor

I am trying to use gedit to view .conf files in Ubuntu server 16.04.2.  I can't seem to do it as you can see:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
[sudo] password for blue: 
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:1430): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: $ sudo gedit
```

I looked for duplicates or similar issues on this forum but it seems to point in using GUI, however I did try to use their workarounds but unfortunately I can't still use it. Anyway you can help me troubleshoot?  I tried re-install but still no joy...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gedit is the official text editor of the GNOME desktop environment. Generally, in a server, there is no desktop environment installed or needed. Therefore, gedit can't start and display.

I suggest that you instead use *nano*.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! great help since I am using only the server and no GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Simply install GNOME:

```
sudo apt -y install gnome
```

Reboot.

Done.

Comment: Doesn't it matter to you from a security standpoint that you recommend installing the GNOME desktop environment, plus a complete range of plugins and other
 applications integrating with GNOME on a server?

Answer (score 0):

> root@TTNPL-6668:~# sudo gedit /etc/profile
> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:8613): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:17:04.209: cannot open display:

> worked for this warning

Simply change user , maybe you are running this command as root
run this command directly from user it will work.